# Is Base 64 and AES base 64 are same?

Tags: android, password-encryption

I've used `Base64` Decoding in to send a password to server in my application. But my server side support suggested me to use AES base64 specifically; I googled about it a bit and found out [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) reason for not to use AES base64 in android; But if I send the normal base64 (in android.util.Base64) encrypted string, can we decrypt it into the original string by using AES base 64?

Comment: `android.util.Base64` does not perform encryption.  You might was well send your password in plaintext.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : Atleast it encodes it; Somewhat better than plain text :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fact that sun implemented some files that are not part of the standard jdk, does not mean you can't find some other impl of them that comply to the same protocol you desire.

In your case, check what you mean by "encryption". After all, base64 is not a way to encrypt/decrypt, just to encode/decode some bytes in a completely reversible way, without any need for a secret key. AES, however, uses a cryptographic key, so it depends if your server is expecting you to send an already AES-encrypted buffer, encoded in base64... you should try to find this out.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I need to encrypt a password, which can compliment AES base64. Any Ideas?

Comment: you would then have to use some AES encryption/decryption library, I'm not sure if Sun's implementation works well within Android apps, I haven't tried it, but I think you should try :) If you use their AES sdk to create an encrypted buffer, you should then base64-encode it and send it to the server. Assuming the server has the secret key, it should be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Do you know any other package rather than the sun?